# Добрый день! Есть поставлення задача. С чего начать советуєте?

Tags: python, dict

Create a function which takes as input two dicts with structure mentioned above, then computes and returns the total price of stock.
Input data:

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

Comment: С чтения учебника по Python, например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните с азов языка.

1. Прочитайте про типы данных (числа, строки, списки, словари) и операции с ними
2. Прочитайте условные операторы и циклы (if ... else, for, while)
   После этого уже без труда решите эту задачу.
   Например, в цикле:

   ```
   s = 0
   for fruit in stock.keys():
       s += stock[fruit]*prices[fruit]
   print(s)
   ```

Или генератором:

```
s = sum(stock[fruit] * prices[fruit] for fruit in stock.keys())
```